# What is the return type of the indexing operation?

Tags: rust

I am trying, quite unsuccessfully, to play around with slices.

I have reduced my first issue to:

```
fn at<'a, T>(slice: &'a [T], index: usize) -> &'a T {
    let item = slice[index];
    item
}
```

It is my expectation that the return type of `slice[index]` be a reference, given the [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html):

```
pub trait Index<Index> {
    type Output;
    fn index(&'a self, index: &Index) -> &'a <Self as Index<Index>>::Output;
//                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
}
```

However, the compiler gives me an error:

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>  --> src/main.rs:3:5
>   |
> 3 |     item
>   |     ^^^^ expected reference, found type parameter
>   |
>   = note: expected type `&'a T`
>              found type `T`
> ```

Which I interpret as meaning that the type of `item` does not match the return type of the function (I introduced `item` solely for debugging purpose, to split expression evaluation from return).

If I switch the return type to `T`, which is the type of `item`, I get another error message:

> ```
> error[E0508]: cannot move out of type `[T]`, a non-copy slice
>  --> src/main.rs:2:16
>   |
> 2 |     let item = slice[index];
>   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^
>   |                |
>   |                cannot move out of here
>   |                help: consider using a reference instead: `&slice[index]`
> ```

After tinkering a bit, I found two work-arounds:

```
fn at<'a, T>(slice: &'a [T], index: usize) -> &'a T {
    &slice[index]
//  ^
}

fn at<'a, T>(slice: &'a [T], index: usize) -> &'a T {
    let ref item = slice[index];
//      ^~~
    item
}
```

forcing the type to be a reference does the trick.

*Why are these shenanigans necessary in the first place?* Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a bit of helpful ergonomics that the compiler does for you in order to make the code look a bit nicer.

The return value of the `Index` trait *is* a reference, but the compiler automatically inserts a dereference for you *when you use the sugared syntax* `[]`. Most other languages would just return the item from the array (copying it or returning another reference to the object, whatever is appropriate).

Due to Rust's importance of move / copy semantics, you can't always make a copy a value, so in those cases, you will usually use a `&`:

```
let items = &[1u8, 2, 3, 4];

let a: u8 = items[0];
let a: u8 = *items.index(&0); // Equivalent of above

let b: &u8 = &items[0];
let b: &u8 = &*items.index(&0); // Equivalent of above
```

Note that the indexing value is also automatically taken by reference, similar to the automatic dereference.

Comment: Ah! I see, so I got caught by the sugar of `[]`! I had not thought about calling `index` directly as I did not expect a difference, even though I had already noticed the difference that calling `[]` with `T` would desugar into calling `index` with `&T`. Thanks for the illustration, it really helps visualizing things.

Answer (score 9):

No, you're doing everything correctly. While `index()` method does return a reference, when it is invoked in an indexing operation its result is dereferenced automatically. This is done so the indexing is more natural: in every language where some kind of indexing operator exists (mainly C and C++), it returns values themselves, not the references into containers.

In order to obtain a reference into the collection you have to either apply a reference operator explicitly (like in your first "workaround") or to use reference pattern (like in the second one).