# What does "cannot move out of index of" mean?

Tags: rust

I am playing with [Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/), and I'm trying to access the first command line argument with this code:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let dir = args[1];
}
```

And I get this error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of indexed content
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
5 |     let dir = args[1];
  |         ---   ^^^^^^^ cannot move out of indexed content
  |         |
  |         hint: to prevent move, use `ref dir` or `ref mut dir`
```

Or in later versions of Rust:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
5 |     let dir = args[1];
  |               ^^^^^^^
  |               |
  |               move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
  |               help: consider borrowing here: `&args[1]`
```

If I change it to `let ref dir`, it compiles, but I don't grok what's going on. Could someone explain what "indexed content" means?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

When you use an index operator (`[]`) you get the actual object at index location. You do not get a reference, pointer or copy. Since you try to bind that object with a `let` binding, Rust immediately tries to move (or copy, if the `Copy` trait is implemented).

In your example, `env::args()` is an iterator of `String`s which is then collected into a `Vec<String>`. This is an owned vector of owned strings, and owned strings are not automatically copyable.

You can use a `let ref` binding, but the more idiomatic alternative is to take a reference to the indexed object (note the `&` symbol):

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let ref dir = &args[1];
    //            ^
}
```

Implicitly moving out of a `Vec` is not allowed as it would leave it in an invalid state — one element is moved out, the others are not. If you have a mutable `Vec`, you can use a method like [`Vec::remove`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.remove) to take a single value out:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let mut args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
    let dir = args.remove(1);
}
```

See also:

- [What is the return type of the indexing operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879161/what-is-the-return-type-of-the-indexing-operation)

---

For your particular problem, you can also just use [`Iterator::nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth):

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
    let dir = env::args().nth(1).expect("Missing argument");
}
```

Comment: What if I own the array, and want to take ownership of a single value in the array (and consume ownership of the array)?

Comment: if it's a `Vec` you can use the `remove` method, otherwise you can `mem::replace` the value with a dummy value.

Comment: `vec.into_iter().nth(1).expect("Missing element")` works

Comment: A remark: the Index trait looks like it should return a reference, but as this answer states, it does not. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879161/what-is-the-return-type-of-the-indexing-operation

Comment: "Rust immidiately tries to move" - why does it try to move instead of passing the ownership of this String?

Comment: Why can't we apply the idea of partial move to `Vec` in this case? i.e., one element is moved out, the rest is intact.

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer has already given the solution. I would like to explain this problem on a semantic level as a complement.

The rule is: **A borrowed value can't be moved out**. See this: [E0507](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error-index.html#E0507)

`[]` operator came from the [Index](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Index%3CI%3E) trait, whose function signature is:

```rust
fn index(&self, index: I) -> &<Vec<T, A> as Index<I>>::Output
```

As you can see, it return a reference, not own the value. Moving it out break the rule mentioned above.

Comment: Content of this answer should be combined to the original answer