# How do I convert a `&T` to just `T`?

Tags: generics, rust

I want to write a function that takes in an array with any type in it and returns the last element of the array, so I've tried:

```
fn main() {
    let v = ["a", "b"];
    println!("{}", last(&v));
}

fn last<T: Clone>(slice: &[T]) -> &T {
    &slice[slice.len()-1]
}
```

and that seems to work, but when I apply a small adjustment:

```
fn main() {
    let v = ["a", "b"];
    println!("{}", last(&v));
}

fn last<T: Clone>(slice: &[T]) -> T {
    &slice[slice.len()-1]
}
```

Then I'm met with:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> <anon>:9:5
  |
9 |     &slice[n-1]
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found &T
  |
 = note: expected type `T`
            found type `&T`
```

How do I convert the `&T` to just `T`?

Comment: Just in case, there's [method `last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.last) for slice

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your first example, you are returning a `&T` and taking a reference to something, so the value and the types match:

```
fn last<T: Clone>(slice: &[T]) -> &T {
//                                ^^
    &slice[slice.len()-1]
//  ^
}
```

But, then you said you weren't going to return a reference anymore, *but didn't change the implementation*.

```
fn last<T: Clone>(slice: &[T]) -> T {
//                                ^
    &slice[slice.len()-1]
//  ^
}
```

`T`, `&T` and `&mut T` are all different types from each other! This means it's the same as this "small adjustment":

```
fn foo() -> i32  { 42 } // Before
fn foo() -> bool { 42 } // After
```

Let's drop the `&` from the body:

```
fn last<T: Clone>(slice: &[T]) -> T {
    slice[slice.len()-1]
}
```

Oops...

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of indexed content
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
4 |         slice[slice.len()-1]
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of indexed content
```

This is well explained in [What does "cannot move out of indexed content" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27904864/155423).

---

The answer to your question is: there's no one right way. There are three broad possibilities:

1. The type implements `Copy` and the compiler automatically dereferences it for you:

   ```
   fn last_copy<T: Copy>(slice: &[T]) -> T {
       slice[slice.len()-1]
   }
   ```
2. The type implements `Clone`, so you can explicitly call `Clone` to duplicate it:

   ```
   fn last_clone<T: Clone>(slice: &[T]) -> T {
       slice[slice.len()-1].clone()
   }
   ```

   There might also be other methods on your type that do something similar.
3. You **don't**. Sometimes, if you have a reference, you can't get a corresponding value. In those cases, you need to re-evaluate your design.