# How to generically move data out of an indexable collection?

Tags: vector, rust, move

The [I/O project example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/book/second-edition/ch12-03-improving-error-handling-and-modularity.html#grouping-configuration-values) in the Rust book suggests cloning the command line args:

```
fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let config = parse_config(&args);
    // ...
}

struct Config {
    query: String,
    filename: String,
}

fn parse_config(args: &[String]) -> Config {
    let query = args[1].clone();
    let filename = args[2].clone();

    Config {
        query, filename
    }
}
```

I would like to move the values into the `Config` struct to avoid the copy.

I tried moving the slice:

```
fn parse_config(args: [String]) -> Config
```

But got the error:

```
the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[std::string::String]`
```

Which makes sense because it's now reading as an unsized array. Next I tried generics:

```
fn parse_config<T: std::ops::Index<usize, Output=String> + Sized>(args: T) -> Config
```

Which gives the error:

```
cannot move out of indexed content
```

This also makes sense, as it would leave the vector in an [invalid state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905403/2736686). I could move the vector:

```
fn parse_config(mut args: Vec<String>) -> Config {
    let query = args.remove(1);
    // ...
```

But now the function is tied to the particular container `Vector`.

How would I write a function that consumes the vector and allows me to move out its contents, while still preserving the generic nature of the function?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to use a consuming iterator:

```
    ...
    let config = parse_config(args.into_iter());
    ...

fn parse_config<T: Iterator<Item=String>>(mut args: T) -> Config {
    let query = args.nth(1).expect("First arg none");
    let filename = args.nth(0).expect("Second arg none");
    ...
}
```

Note that the `nth` function is advancing and consuming the iterator, so that instead of the second argument indexing at `2`, it is now one iteration later, i.e. `0`.

Comment: `nth(0)` is usually written `next()`. Also note that your answer has nothing to do with the collection being "indexable".

Comment: No need for the `collect` above, and then the `into_iter` call; you should be able to pass `env::args()` directly to this function, no?