# Cannot return a vector slice - ops::Range<i32> is not implemented

Tags: rust

Why does the following Rust code give an error?

```
fn getVecSlice(vec: &Vec<f64>, start: i32, len: i32) -> &[f64] {
    vec[start..start + len]
}
```

The error message I get is

```
the trait `core::ops::Index<core::ops::Range<i32>>` is not implemented for the type `collections::vec::Vec<f64>` [E0277]
```

In later versions of Rust, I get

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::ops::Range<i32>: std::slice::SliceIndex<[f64]>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:2:9
  |
2 |         vec[start..start + len]
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ slice indices are of type `usize` or ranges of `usize`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::slice::SliceIndex<[f64]>` is not implemented for `std::ops::Range<i32>`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::ops::Index<std::ops::Range<i32>>` for `std::vec::Vec<f64>`
```

I'm trying to simulate a 2 dimensional matrix using the `Vec` type and return references to the different rows of the matrix.What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Convention would name the function `get_vec_slice`, and would also largely refrain from such a trivial method. It would also probably take `&[f64]` rather than `&Vec<f64>`; `&Vec<f64>` is silently coercible to `&[f64]`, so there is no loss there. It would also for convenience probably be made generic instead of specific to `f64`…

Comment: Cheers for the advice. I'm still battling with the Rust compiler so much, I haven't really begun to absorb the conventions and idioms.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The error messages tells you that you can't index into a vector with values of type `u32`. `Vec` indices have to be of type `usize`, so you have to cast your indices to that type like this:

```
vec[start as usize..(start + len) as usize]
```

or just change the type of the `start` and `len` arguments to `usize`.

You also [need to take a reference to the result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879161/155423):

```
&vec[start as usize..(start + len) as usize]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Why do we need usize:**

`usize` gives you the guarantee to be always big enough to hold any pointer or any offset in a data structure, while `u32` can be too small on some architectures.

As an example, on a 32 bit x86 computer, `usize = u32`, while on x86_64 computers, `usize = u64`.