# What is the differences between the two slice in Rust?

Tags: rust, slice

```
let s1 = String::from("hello world.");
let r1 = &s1;
let sl1 = &s1[..];
let sl2 = &r1[..];
let sl3 = r1[..];
println!("{}", sl3);
```

What is the difference between `sl1` and `sl2`, and why `sl3` is invalid? Isn't `r1` a reference already, why need `&`?

Comment: Would the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879161/what-is-the-return-type-of-the-indexing-operation-on-a-slice) also answer yours?

Comment: Regarding the question about the difference between `sl1` and `sl2`, there isn't any.  Both cause the `String` to be dereferenced to a slice, and the slice is then indexed with a range.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/279627

Answer (score 1):

The compiler *dereferences* the output of `Index::index` when desugaring the indexing syntax `[]` (see related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879161/what-is-the-return-type-of-the-indexing-operation-on-a-slice) and its answers). Using explicit type annotations, the types of the bindings are thus as follows:

```
let r1: &str = &s1;
let sl1: &str = &s1[..];
let sl2: &str = &r1[..];
let sl3: str = r1[..];
```

`str`, being an unsized type, cannot be put on the stack and therefore cannot be used as the type for a local variable binding `sl3`, hence the compile error.