# Is it possible to have a non-borrowed slice?

Tags: rust, slice

If I try this:

```
let vector = vec![1, 2, 3];
let slice = vector[1..2];
```

I get a compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[{integer}]: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:9
  |
3 |     let slice = vector[1..2];
  |         ^^^^^   ------------ help: consider borrowing here: `&vector[1..2]`
  |         |
  |         `[{integer}]` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[{integer}]`
  = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
```

I get that we need `let slice = &vector[1..2]` as the compiler kindly suggests. This makes sense: a slice *always* comes from another value, thus you need to borrow the vector in this example.

However, I tried this:

```
let vector = vec![1, 2, 3];
let borrowed_vector = &vector;
let slice = borrowed_vector[1..2];
```

and I am back to the same error.

I ask because it seems a bit weird to require the `&vector[]` syntax if in fact borrowing (`&`) is always required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A non-borrowed slice (`[T]`) exists, but you cannot use it as value as-is. It is only useful in other types where it is behind a pointer of some kind. For example (not exhaustive):

- In borrowed slices: `&[T]`
- In boxed slices (*i.e.* owned slices): `Box<[T]>`
- In ref-counted slices: `Rc<[T]>`

That is because the compiler cannot know what the size of an unsized type on the stack but a pointer has a known size.

The type can also be used as part of a trait bound for static polymorphism: `U: AsRef<[T]>`.

> It seems a bit weird to require this syntax `&vector[]` if in fact borrowing (`&`) is always required.

It is not always required to use an `&` with the indexing syntax because [sometimes the referenced value can be dereferenced](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html):

```
let scores = vec![1, 2, 3];
let score = scores[0];
```

See also:

- [What is the return type of the indexing operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27879161/155423)